# Working of pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

```
main()
{
char *table[] = {"jan","feb","march"};
char **ptr =&table[1];
printf("%c",(*++*--ptr));
}
```

`*` and prefix `++/--` same precedence and R-> L associativity

`**ptr` has address of `feb`

`--ptr` will go to `jan` address

`*--ptr` dereference `ptr` which point to `jan`

`++*--` increment pointer value `j` to 1

`*++*--` deference above value means `a`

Is my understanding correct ? If not please explain wrong understood statement. My doubt is whether `--ptr` go to address of `jan` or some other address. I am not sure about it.

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: Yes. You are almost correct.  *`**ptr` has address of `feb`* should be *`ptr` has address of `feb`*.

Comment: Of course @gr I have tried to understand that's why I have explained the steps but I am not quite sure whether I am wrong or right that why I asked question.

Comment: @haccks Thanks for response. I agree with you . But `--ptr` refer to address   of  `jan` ? What I am thinking is if we do `--ptr` the address of `ptr` is decremented not address of `feb`. So how it will go to address of `jan` ?

Comment: `--ptr` subtracts `sizeof(char *)` from its value, so it will point to the previous `char *` which is `"jan"`.

Comment: Thanks @grc . this is what exact answer of my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should split the instruction on multiple lines if you want to be sure:

```c
char *table[] = {"jan","feb","march"};
char **ptr = &table[1];
// This: 
*++*--ptr;
// Is the same as:
ptr = ptr - 1; // prefix --
*ptr = *ptr + 1; // prefix ++ on *--ptr
**ptr;
```

Since you know the precedence of all operators, you can easily do that, and now it is much  more readable.

One way to understand what happen at this point is to look at what you memory could look like (assuming `sizeof(void*) == 2`, and all pointers type have same `sizeof`):

```
// Somewhere in the rodata segment (these are probably contiguous, but I don't really care).
// The 0 are for the null character at the end.
0x1241: jan0
0x1542: feb0
0x1712: march0

// Somewhere in your stack
0x8742: 0x1241 0x1542 0x171 // This is table (contiguous)
0x8844: 0x8744 // This is ptr
```

The first instruction is `ptr = ptr - 1`, since `ptr` is of type `char **`, `ptr - 1` is going to decrement the value of `ptr` by `sizeof(*ptr)` (which is `sizeof(char*)`). So in our example, `ptr` is going to be decremented by `2`:

```
0x8844: 0x8742 // after --ptr
```

You clearly see that `ptr` contains `&table[0]` (or the decay value of `table` to `char **`).

The second instruction is `*ptr = *ptr + 1`, so you are going to increment the value pointed by `ptr`, which is the value stored (in our example) at the address `0x8742`, which is the first cell of `table`:

```
0x8742: 0x1242 0x1542 0x171
```

By how much did you increment the value of `*ptr`? Well, by `sizeof(**ptr)`, which is `sizeof(char)` (assumed `1` in this example), so you get `0x1242 = 0x1241 + 1`.

Finally the third instruction is simply `**ptr`, so you first get the value at the address pointed by `ptr` (which is `0x1242`), and then you get the value at this address, which is `'a'`.

---

**Extra...** If you want to check your understanding of the above, you should think of what would the following output (before and after your original `printf`):

```
printf("%s", table[0]);
```

Before, you are going to get `jan` (as expected), but after...

This is going to output only `an` (and not `jan`). Why? Because when you did `++*--ptr`, which is the same as:

```
ptr = ptr - 1;
*ptr = *ptr + 1;
```

You modified the value pointed by `ptr`. What was this value? Well, after `ptr = ptr - 1;`, `ptr` was pointing to `&table[0]`, so `*ptr` was `table[0]` so when you did `*ptr = *ptr + 1;`, you incremented `table[0]`.

At the beginning, `table[0]` was pointing to the `j` in `jan`, but after incrementing it, it is pointing to the `a`.

Comment: What an explanation :-) . Thanks you I am really satisfied

Comment: @PunitVara Thanks. This is a bit off-topic for this question, but you should also know that declaring `table` as `char *table[]` instead of `const char *table[]` is a bit "dangerous" because in your example, `++**ptr` is valid (compiler will be ok with that), but is wrong (you are trying to modify a read-only value), and thus your program is going to crash miserably.

Comment: Thank you :-) .It added crystal clear info to my brain. This is actually workbook problem I will not use this for any production code as you warned me about it.

Comment: and you asked me to guess `table[0]`. Is it 'jan' right ?

Comment: @PunitVara No, `printf("%s", table[0])` will only output `an` because you modify the content of `table[0]` when you did `*ptr = *ptr + 1` (in the memory, you see that at the beginning `table[0]` contains `0x1241`, which points to `'j'`, thus outputing `jan`, but at the end it contains `0x1242`, which points to `'a'`, thus outputing only `an`).

Comment: ohh I thought you were asking before modification.

Answer (score 2):

> **ptr has address of feb

Thats not true. ptr has adress of `feb`.

> --ptr will go to jan address

Thats true. `ptr` is adress of `feb` so `ptr-1` is adress of `jan`

> - and prefix ++/-- same precedence and R-> L associativity

correct

Answer (score 2):

Here are some pointers that I always keep in mind while solving these kind of problems.

Whenever you see `*` in the code (other than declaration or multiplication), say it as `value of` (loud, inside your head) and whenever you see `&`, say it as `address of`.

Now, I'm just changing your code a little:

```
main()
{
char *table[] = {"jan","feb","march"};
char **ptr;
ptr = &table[1];
printf("%c",(*++*--ptr));
}
```

Your code is correct, and so is mine (syntactically) and both are exactly same. When you initialize any `pointer` while declaring, it is done as you have, otherwise, any time later in the code, you don't attach `**` to it.

So, `**ptr` has address of `feb` -> **NO**, because, `ptr` has it. Actually, `**ptr = f`, as it is (value at(value at(address of "feb"))), which is, (value at(address of "f")) , which is, `f`.

Now, since `ptr` holds address of `feb`, `ptr - 1` will hold address of `jan`. So, `*--ptr = jan` as `--ptr` subtracts `sizeof(char *)` from its value, so it will point to the previous `char *` which is "jan".

Now, if `*--ptr = jan`, then, `(*--ptr) + 1` holds address of `a`, which when you dereference it, gives you `a`.

Comment: I thought of it while writing the answer, :D :D

Comment: Thank you for awesome answer

Comment: `--ptr subtracts sizeof(char *) from its value, so it will point to the previous char * which is "jan".` can you please include this line in answer ? Thanks @grc for this comment. It improved my understanding

Comment: Thanks for it. Above answer is really crystal clear to me Sorry I did not accept your answer . But thanks for efforts you have made